# Fill with Layout until next layout (at bottom)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

So, I have a header, and then a CardView that should fill the screen until the footer. Problem is, it fills all the screen, and the footer goes "under" the screen, as you can see in the images.

I want to keep the footer (button + the two images) always at the bottom and the cardview should always fill the rest of the screen. There is a scrollview in the cardview that will allow text to be read in the cardview.

Anyway, here is the **XML code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qstView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Insert question text here"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_full_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:onClick="onAddAnswer"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"
        android:text="Suivant"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:src="@drawable/ineedhelp"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:src="@drawable/mbtouch_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is what I have at the moment:**

[image: Relative Layout - I have at the moment]

And **this is what I would like to have** (here I forced dimensions, but since not all devices are the same, the space will not be used optimally).

[image: Relative Layout - I want]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try using ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout. I find it much easier to get elements exactly where I want them when using that layout format. You would constrain your button and logos to the bottom of the screen with padding, and then have your card fill the available space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to arrange your view like the manner below (For `CardView` and bottom layout, rest things will stay as they were)..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ....
    ...>

     <!--  Since, weight is 1 it will occupy whole space subtracting height of bottom  -->
     <CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        .... />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ....>

        <!--  Put your bottom widgets over here  -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```